# How to convert HEX into two digits format?

Tags: java, android

I want to convert a decimal number into HEX. For example `14` into `E` but then I want to convert `E` into two digits format like `0E`. This is my code but its given me an error.

```
int lightOnHours = 14;
Log.d("Two Digits", String.format("%02s",Integer.toHexString(lightOnHours));
```

**Error Message**

```
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832): java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: %s does not support '0'
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1359)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1440)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1079)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1040)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1009)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1998)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1972)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at com.test.digits.TestFragment2$5.onClick(TestFragment2.java:158)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
07-11 16:57:32.422: E/AndroidRuntime(12832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `s` format specifier for `String.format`, you can use the `x` specifier which formats an integer as hexadecimal:

```
String.format("%02x", lightOnHours)
```

Or `X` if you prefer uppercase hexadecimal:

```
String.format("%02X", lightOnHours)
```

Comment: Chose your answer as the solution for given more details

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
String.format("%02X", lightOnHours)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.format("%02X", lightOnHours)`

Comment: That does something completely different

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
int lightOnHours = 14;
System.out.println(
        Integer.toHexString(lightOnHours).length()==1
        ?"0"+Integer.toHexString(lightOnHours)
        :Integer.toHexString(lightOnHours)
);
```